# Composite functions, is this statement correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition

Let $S = \{1,2,3,4\}$. Let $f$ be the sets of all functions from $S$ to $S$.

Now, is this statement correct?

$\forall f \in F$ , $\exists$  $g \in F$ so that $(f\circ g) (1) = 2$

I think this is false because suppose the only output $f(x)$ can produce is

$f(x)=3$ and $f(x) = 4$

Now, there is no possibility of $(f\circ g)(1) = 2$ because $2$ isn't an output of $f$.

Is that correct to say?

Comment: Yes.  This could be tidied up a bit, but it is the correct idea.  I would phrase it as "Consider the constant function $f~:~ S\to S$ such that $f(x)=4$ for all $x$.  Then for any $g\in F$ recognize that $g(x)\in S$ for each $x$ and so for each $x$ we have $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))=4\neq 2$, providing a counterexample to the claim"

Comment: Thanks that really helps!

Comment: @GottfriedHelms That's actually a slightly different question : $f$ and $g$ are switched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.  Perhaps easier is to consider $f(x)=1$ for all $x$, but the idea is the same.